# InvalidOperationException: CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter 'link_type=General' in Request.QueryString on page

Tags: html, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working in CRM2011/OnPrem with a custom dialog.  This custom dialog has links in it that are supposed to take you to an existing contact entity page, with two different forms(formA and formsB) and a certain section/tab within that page (General, address, etc).  Most of the time this works great.  If the user clicks on the link to take you to the "General" section/tab the dialog generates a link that looks like

```
http://aaa/bbb/main.aspx?etc=2&extraqs=etc%3D2%26id%3D%7Bd6dc6bc2-b3b1-e211-9aab-  
d067e5e55c13%7D%26link_type%3DGeneral&pagetype=entityrecord,
```

opens that link in a new tab and IE takes you to the proper section.

If the user has selected formB as their default, the dialog creates the exact same link as above, tries to take to you the exact same page, loads the ribbon, but then the page crashes and I am given an error message of :InvalidOperationException: CRM Parameter Filter - Invalid parameter 'link_type=General' in Request.QueryString on page...

I have double checked and both forms have the same sections that we are linking to and the sections names and labels are the same.

Thoughts?  Is there a way to format the url so it works for both forms?  Any other ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom form parameters are set per form. Based on your description, it's likely that formA has the parameters set, while form B doesn't. Add the params to form B and see if that works.